# Load page dynamically using slide left to right effect

Tags: jquery, dynamic, slide

Want to load page dynamically without page refresh like this [site](http://www.vizio.com/m-series/overview).  If you click the features, gallery link it gets slide left and new page load dynamically. Is there is any plugin to do that..?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using JQuery and function animate is the simplest solution.

You can create 3 divs object on your page. When an user clicks link, you load content asynchronously into correct div and when ajax call succeds, you just use animate function from JQuery to move the divs.

These are some good tutorials to begin with:

[JQuery animate function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

[JQuery ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I need some plug and play plugin.